# django_mongokit 0.2.6 not working in Django 1.11

Tags: django, mongokit

I installed django_mongokit 0.2.6, but it's not working in Django 1.11.
While run server shows below error,
$ python manage.py runserver

```
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
u'base', u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: cannot import name BaseDatabaseOperations
```

Django : (1.11)
Pymongo : (2.5)
django-mongokit : (0.2.6)
pymongo : (2.8)
PyMySQL : (0.8.0)

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'example',        
},
'mongodb': {
    'ENGINE': 'django_mongokit.mongodb',
    'NAME': 'example',        
},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the [README](https://github.com/peterbe/django-mongokit#troubleshooting):

> If you get this error:
>
> [...]
>
> Then it's simply because you don't have mongokit itself installed.

`pip install mongokit` should help.